# What ( int & 1) != 0 mean

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today I manage some code from old person. The value of test1 is load from db, I will try to make easier like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#checkWeekday").click(function () {
    checkWeekday();
  })
});

function GetRepeatDOWs(_RepeatDOWs) {
  let WeekDay = [];
  if ((_RepeatDOWs & 1) != 0) {
    WeekDay.push(0);
  }
  if ((_RepeatDOWs & 2) != 0) {
    WeekDay.push(1);
  }
  if ((_RepeatDOWs & 4) != 0) {
    WeekDay.push(2);
  }
  if ((_RepeatDOWs & 8) != 0) {
    WeekDay.push(3);
  }
  if ((_RepeatDOWs & 16) != 0) {
    WeekDay.push(4);
  }
  if ((_RepeatDOWs & 32) != 0) {
    WeekDay.push(5);
  }
  if ((_RepeatDOWs & 64) != 0) {
    WeekDay.push(6);
  }
  return WeekDay;
}

function getWeekday(val) {
  switch (val) {
    case 0:
      console.log('Sunday');
      break;
    case 1:
      console.log('Mon');
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log('Tuesday ');
      break;
    case 3:
      console.log('Wen');
      break;
    case 4:
      console.log('Thur');
      break;
    case 5:
      console.log('Fri');
      break;
    case 6:
      console.log('Sat');
      break;
  }
}

function checkWeekday() {
  let check = parseInt($("#test1").val());
  var a = GetRepeatDOWs(check);
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    getWeekday(a[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type ="text" id ="test1" value='127'>

<input type ="button" id="checkWeekday"  value="test">
```

From code above you can see: number 127 is on for all day of week, 3 is on for Sunday and Monday, how does it work? what mathematics thay has been stored in database?

Comment: The `&` operator is a binary AND operation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is the bitwise AND operator. It compares the values (in 32 bit binary) bit by bit. For each place where both values have a 1, a 1 is output, if they both have a 0 or one has a 0 and the other a 1, a 0 is output.

For example:

The binary for 8 is: `1000`
The binary for 12 is: `1100`

Comparing these two, we see that only the left most digit is 1 for both values.

So the result is `1000`, or 8.

```js
// show binary of 8
console.log( (8 >>> 0).toString(2) );

// show binary of 12
console.log( (12 >>> 0).toString(2) );

// show result of 8 & 12
console.log( 8 & 12 );
```

Answer (score 2):

`if ((_RepeatDOWs & 1) != 0)` checks if the lowest bit in `_RepeatDOWs` is `1`.

`if ((_RepeatDOWs & 2) != 0)` checks if the second bit in `_RepeatDOWs` is `1`.

...

`if ((_RepeatDOWs & 8) != 0)` checks if the fourth bit in `_RepeatDOWs` is `1`.

and so on.

Comment: More info. here would be helpful. Like what is the binary `&` operator, how it checks if the first, second, etc. bit is a 1, why you'd want to do that, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple implementation of a bit set. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array
You don't see this kind of low level hacks used much these days. Modem code would use a `Set` instead.

A bit set data structure can represent a set of up to n items as a number of n bits, where a bit being "on" (or 1) corresponds to the item being present. If the bit is off (0) the item is not present. A bit is numerically a power of two: the first item is 1, the second item is 2, then 4, 8, 16, and so on.

The bitwise AND operation computes the intersection of two sets ("what items are present in both sets"). Likewise, OR computes the union ("what items are present in at least one set").

In the code you've found, the items are days of week. There are 7 days, so you need 7 bits. A set with Sunday and Monday isnumerically  1+2=3. A set with all days of week is  1+2+4+8+...+64=127.

Answer (score 1):

some examples to cogitate

```js
document.write('127 ->', (127).toString(2),'<br>')
document.write('0b1111111 ->', (0b1111111).toString(10),'<br>')

document.write('1 ->', (1).toString(2),'<br>')
document.write('2 ->', (2).toString(2),'<br>')
document.write('4 ->', (4).toString(2),'<br>')
document.write('8 ->', (8).toString(2),'<br>')
document.write('16 ->', (16).toString(2),'<br>')

document.write('127 & 4 ->', (127 & 4).toString(2),'<br>')

document.write('0b1111011 & 4 -> ', (0b1111011 & 4).toString(2),'<br>')
document.write('0b1111011 | 4 -> ', (0b1111011 | 4).toString(2),'<br>')
```